# Tab Bar view does not load

Tags: iphone, xcode

In my app delegate interface I have:

```
@interface pivcalc1AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
IBOutlet UITabBarController *RootController;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *Window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *RootController;
```

in implementation, I have:

```
@synthesize Window;
@synthesize RootController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

[Window addSubview:RootController.view];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[self.Window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

In my main xib window I have a tab bar controller which is connected to app delegate as rootController.
When I run the program, the window shows but the tab bar view does not get loaded.
Appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you have a subViewController in RootController in xib? if you're not, It's code following.

UITabBarController should be have a subViewController.

```
    UINavigationController *localNavigationController;

    NSMutableArray *localViewControllerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

    SubViewController *subviewController0 = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:subviewController0];
    [localViewControllerArray addObject:localNavigationController];
    [subviewController0 release];
    [localNavigationController release];

    SubViewController *subviewController1 = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:subviewController1];
    [localViewControllerArray addObject:localNavigationController];
    [subviewController1 release];

    [localNavigationController release];

    RootController.viewControllers = localViewControllerArray;
    [localViewControllerArray release];

    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution you provided.  But my problem was that my tab bar item view controller nib name had extension.  I eliminated the extension "xib" and everything is a charm now.